# How to compare values within an array in Python - find out whether 2 values are the same

Tags: python, arrays, list

I basically have an array of 50 integers, and I need to find out whether any of the 50 integers are equal, and if they are, I need to carry out an action.

How would I go about doing this? As far as I know there isn't currently a function in Python that does this is there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean you have a list and you want to know if there are any duplicate values, then make a set from the list and see if it's shorter than the list:

```
if len(set(my_list)) < len(my_list):
    print "There's a dupe!"
```

This won't tell you what the duplicate value is, though.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!
One more thing though, if there is a duplicate value within the list, why will the length of the the list change when converted to a set? Do sets automatically remove duplicates? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you have Python 2.7+ you can use [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
>>> import collections
>>> input = [1, 1, 3, 6, 4, 8, 8, 5, 6]
>>> c = collections.Counter(input)
>>> c
Counter({1: 2, 6: 2, 8: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1})
>>> duplicates = [i for i in c if c[i] > 1]
>>> duplicates
[1, 6, 8]
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution if you need to know *which* number appears more than once.

Comment: nice I did not know this one. Better than my answer indeed (+1)

Answer (score 2):

If your actions need to know the number or how many times that number gets repeated over your input list then `groupby` is a good choice.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> for x in groupby([1,1,2,2,2,3]):
...     print x[0],len(list(x[1]))
... 
1 2
2 3
3 1
```

The first number is the element and the second the number of repetitions. `groupby` works over a sorted list so make sure you sort your input list, for instance.

```
>>> for x in groupby(sorted([1,1,2,4,2,2,3])):
...     print x[0],len(list(x[1]))
... 
1 2
2 3
3 1
4 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the list to a Set, and check their lengths.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> len(set(a)) == len(a)
True
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
>>> len(set(a)) == len(a)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> arbitrary_list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]
>>> item_occurence = dict([(item, list.count(item)) for item in arbitrary_list])
{1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 3}
```

If you want to see which values are not unique you can get a list of those values by

```
>>> filter(lambda item: item_occurence[item] > 1, item_occurence)
[1, 4]
```